# NetworkX most efficient way to find the longest path in a DAG at start vertex with no errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs, longest-path

Starting from a certain vertex, how would one find the longest path relative to that vertex? I've been browsing all over and can't find a solution to this problem which actually works for all possible cases of DAGs. Source code in NetworkX would be preferred but regular python is fine too. Im genuinely curious as to why I can't manage to find any proper working example, I do understand it is an NP-type problem but I would like to know the most efficient way it is done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would check if this graph is connected. If so, then the longest path is the path across all nodes. If not, it means this vertex is contained in a connected component. Then I would use [`connected_component_subgraphs`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html) to find the largest component this vertex lies in. After that, the longest path is the path across all nodes in this largest component.

Of course, this works only if you don't allow cycles in your path.

```
import networkx as nx 
G = nx.DiGraph()  
G.add_edges_from([(0,1),(0,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,6),(6,1),(0,2),(2,3),(1,2)])  
for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=0, target=3):  
    print(path)
```

The result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

The third one is what you like.

Comment: I understand the logic behind this but I've tried a very long time to try solve this, I'm at a point where I just need to learn off a correct source code

Comment: Mind you, I also want to know a very efficient way to do so, brute forcing paths is not what I'd want to be doing. I'd like a source code along the lines of a more efficient "brute force", that is, calculating some path starting from a vertex and if the vertex happens to be spotted in another iteration we can just end shortly by adding the current path to the already computed path

Comment: I think all graph search algorithm in NetworkX is by brute force. Also I don't get why `dfs_tree` does not meet your need.

Comment: Because it wont give us the longest path, if we conduct a dfs on a tree, it will give us a path, but if we think about an alternative path from the root that might connect up to a path thats already seen it wont return the sum of the length of those two paths wont it? Or am I mistaken

Comment: I don't quite understand how dfs will give you the longest path in a tree, see [link]http://imgur.com/EcTcpZv[link] the longest path is clearly 6 but the longest path from a dfs will give 3 since the edge from '6' to '1' will have already been visited before. If we ignore the part about graphs having loops what is the most definite way I can find the longest path?

Comment: You are right. Neither BFS or DFS are shortest path oriented. But I find this function `all_simple_path`. I tested on the graph you created. I just add a code example above in the answer.

Comment: This is also wrong in the case that if I don't know what my end vertex is right? If I am given some graphs that I do not know what the target is then I can't find the longest path

Comment: So what about the case where you don't know the target?

Comment: Then you can omit the `target` argument.